# Serializing and deserializing objects with arbitrary fields using Json.NET in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'd like to serialize and deserialize objects with arbitrary fields. I've tried to have the object with the arbitrary fields extend `Dictionary<string, object>` in hopes that I would be able to set the arbitrary fields as Dictionary entries. In this case I expect to have `Company` and `Position` in the json response (listed in code comments) in addition to the `manager` and `office` fields. Unfortunately I'm able get the arbitrary fields but unable to get the non arbitrary fields.

I would also like to be able to add arbitrary objects, not just strings (ie add a salary object with base salary, bonus, etc to the job). I also have some restrictions and cannot use `dynamic` for this.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}

public class Job : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}

var job = new Job()
{
    Company = "Super Mart",
    Position = "Cashier"
};

// Set arbitrary fields
job["manager"] = "Kathy";
job["office"] = "001";

var john = new Person()
{
    Name = "John Doe",
    Age = 41,
    Job = job
};

var employeeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(john, Formatting.Indented);
Log.Debug("TestSerialization", "json: {0}", employeeJson);
// Result
// {
//   "Name": "John Doe",
//   "Age": 41,
//   "Job": {
//     "manager": "Kathy",
//     "office": "001"
//   }
// }

var johnDoe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(employeeJson);
Log.Debug("TestSerialization", "name: {0}, age: {1}", johnDoe.Name, johnDoe.Age);
// Result
// name: John Doe, age: 41

Log.Debug("TestSerialization", "company: {0}, position: {1}", johnDoe.Job.Company, johnDoe.Job.Position);
// Result
// company: , position:

Log.Debug("TestSerialization", "manager: {0}, office: {1}", johnDoe.Job["manager"], johnDoe.Job["office"]);
// Result
// manager: Kathy, office: 001
```

My result json from deserialization using this code is

```
{
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Age": 41,
  "Job": {
    "manager": "Kathy",
    "office": "001"
  }
}
```

I would like the result json to be (what the service would expect)

```
{
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Age": 41,
  "Job": {
    "Company" = "Super Mart",
    "Position" = "Cashier"
    "manager": "Kathy",
    "office": "001"
  }
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear what result you get and what result you expect. Can you provide this information?

Comment: The results are listed in comments in the code block. What I would like to get is `company` and `position` - the two non arbitrary fields in the `Job` model to not be null.

Comment: You I probably are looking for custom contract resolvers.

Comment: The results are listed, but it's not clear, what result you expect. Please modify your question by adding final json version, that you want to get.

Comment: I apologize - I added explicit results and expectation to the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your job Class, it derived from a dictionary so when you serialize it will not consider its members. only dictionary values,

Try this way, I am not sure this will help your context

```
public class Job 
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> job { get; set; }

    public Job()
    {
        job = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

Debug.Log(johnDoe.Job.job["manager"]+"-"+ johnDoe.Job.job["office"]);

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work in my case. The `Job` class needs to have explicit `Company` and `Position` properties while at the same time accept arbitrary properties. I added an example of what the server would expect in the question.